# Legend and Fieldset are not working in my code

Tags: html, css

I'm programming and I want to make a text between lines, however, the legend and fieldset method is not working

My html code:

```css
.faleConosco {
  width: 100vw;
}

.faleConosco fieldset {
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.faleConosco fieldset legend {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="faleConosco">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Produtos</legend>
  </fieldset>
</section>
```

What happens:
[image]

Comment: do you have any other css?

Comment: I don't have other css

Comment: your code seems to work

Comment: where can i send you my whole code?

Comment: edit your question and provided [mcve]

Comment: I just saw that it really works, I really don't know the error